# TextPad: Find all the lines not starting with a pattern and replace with a back space

Tags: textpad

I want to introduce a backspace character at the beginning of the line where a particular pattern is not found. Please advise.

Thanks,
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to "remove the first character" then you can do this:

1) Write your regex pattern of what you want to find. For example, if you want to match `Remove me` at the start of the line, use:

`^R\(emove me\)`

Here we use ^ to assert the position to the start of the string. We also capture everything apart from the string we wish to keep in a backreference so it can be used later.

2) Replace the matches we find with whatever we grabbed in our backreference, in this case `emove me`, in effect *backspacing* the first character.

3) Make sure regular expression is checked and the cursor is at the start of the file, and hit `Replace All`.

**Before**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image]